# Console application crashes for unknown reason

Tags: c

I have my piece of code which is shown  below

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    int a;
    printf("Please select a choice \n1.Enter New Artist\n2.List All Artist information\n3.   Show sorted List of Artists\n4.Add Album to existing Artist\n5.Remove Album from existing Artist\n6.Update Artist info\n7.Search for Artist");
    scanf("%d,&a");
    if(a==1)
    {
        printf("no");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

On running the code, it displays the menu and if i input `1`, it takes a few seconds before it crashes and displays the info

> document1.exe has stopped working

How can I debug this problem. I am using `dev c++ 4.9.9.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `scanf` statement is wrong. You are not passing argument (pointer) to it.

Change

```
scanf("%d,&a");
```

to

```
 scanf("%d",&a);
```

Comment: thank you silly mistake but it was making me so anxious, will accept after 15

Comment: Sorry! I misunderstood :)

Answer (score 1):

For a C solution - I am not certain
aside from previously mentioned
error in scanf formatting (which your compiler should have warned about),
which would have put the result.. well, god knows where on stack…
I'm not certain, but I suspect the compiled code would take the next location in ram as an address, and write there.
Borked stack == really, really, really hard to debug errors.

Since you are using a c++ compiler, if you can use c++,  you may wish to consider evaluation of using some of the STL here.
I assume you will be terminating input with a CR

```
int main (int argv, char** argv]
{

    int a;
    std::string inputString;
    std::cout <<"Please select a choice \n""1.Enter New Artist\n2.List All Artist information\n3.   Show sorted List of Artists\n4.Add Album to existing Artist\n5.Remove Album from existing Artist\n6.Update Artist info\n7.Search for Artist";
    std::getline(std::cin,inputString);
    std::stringstream inputStream(inputString);
    inputStream >> a;  // could also have been parsed with std::stol, or strtol. - my preference due to error checking - what if your user entered 'byte me'?  
    if (a==1)
    {
        printf("no");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```